# How to print Indian Rupee Sign on Epson TM-T88VI receipt printer?

Tags: printing, epson, receipt, opos

How do I print the Indian rupee sign ( ₹ / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign ) on the Epson TM-T88VI receipt printer?

I know how to print simplified Chinese (as per my article here: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/01/15/Simplified-Chinese-on-Epson-TM-T88IV-Receipt-Printer.aspx )

However, the new rupee sign does not appear in the list of known characters on the printer, in any supported character set:
https://pos.epson.com/download/?AssetPK=24978

Do you have any creative options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DirectIO call to upload a new character glyph to the "User Defined Page (255)".